# Disable email field for create account during WooCommerce checkout when guest is creating account in checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how should I disable the email field in checkout ( billing ) in woocommerce when a guest user wants to create an account?
I would like the username's user to be created by phone.
Many thanks for your help and your response, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does these help ; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/user-without-email, http://docwordpress.com/overrides/allow-registration-new-wordpress-users-without-email-address/ I know these are for wordpress, but you can woocommerce is user is a specialized wordpress user with customer role. You might want to clarify your question better. And show us what you have actually tired.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I want to remove the Email field when a new user wants to create a new account during putting a new order ( when sign up required to buy ), and then assign the phone field to username without considering the Email filed the username.